# opencv for java videowriter can't open

Tags: java, opencv

I'm using opencv3.1.0 in java. I want to save video to file, but videowriter can't open. My code below:

```
Size size = new Size(capture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), capture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
double fps = capture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS);
VideoWriter vw = new VideoWriter("/home/sify/1.mp4", VideoWriter.fourcc('X', '2', '6', '4'), fps, size, true);
```

vw.isOpened() returns false. No file is created.

I'm suspecting it's something wrong with fourcc.

I tried to use H264/XVID/FMP4/MPEG, and tried to replace the second parameter with (int)capture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FOURCC), also not working.

Comment: I changed "1.mp4" to "1.avi" and used "MJPG" and it succeed, but I don't know why. The output file is very large in size. Does opencv only support avi output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The openCV download contains the mp4 codec in the dynamic link library file `opencv_ffmpeg343_64.dll`.  To make that visible to the JVM, run a lines like this before you open the VideoWriter.

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "C:\pathToFolderContainingDLL")
val fieldSysPath = ClassLoader::class.java.getDeclaredField("sys_paths")
fieldSysPath.isAccessible = true
fieldSysPath.set(null, null)
//next time path is accessed, the new path will be imported

System.loadLibrary("opencv_ffmpeg343_64")
```

Comment: How can i do this solution in Java for an Android project?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is codec, try this.

```
int fourcc = VideoWriter.fourcc('m','j','p','g');
Size frameSize = new Size((int) videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),(int) videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
VideoWriter videoWriter = new VideoWriter("testfile.avi", fourcc, 20, frameSize, true);
 if (videoCapture.read(frame))
      videoWriter.write(frame);
```

Comment: OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x67706a6d/'mjpg' is not supported with codec id 7 and format 'mpeg / MPEG-1 Systems / MPEG program stream'