# Java, OpenCV VideoWriter isOpened returns always false

Tags: java, opencv, video-capture

I am using Java OpenJdk 14.0.2 and OpenCV-440 as well while everything is running on Windows 10. My JavaFX application is supposed to capture the frames of a webcam (or any other video device) and store the frames as a video file, for example avi.

Here is my code:

```
   public void run() {

        Mat frame = new Mat();
        VideoCapture videoCapture = new VideoCapture(0);
        videoCapture.read(frame);

        Size frameSize = new Size((int) videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), (int) videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
        int fourcc = VideoWriter.fourcc('x', '2','6','4');
        VideoWriter writer = new VideoWriter();
        //if myuniquefile%02d.jpg is using any kind of video extension instead, it is not working (e.g. avi)
        writer.open("images/myuniquefile%02d.jpg", fourcc,
                videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS), frameSize, true);
        
        while (isRunning) {
            if (videoCapture.read(frame)) {
                writer.write(frame);
            }
        }
        videoCapture.release();
        writer.release();
    }
```

This code is working fine, but as soon I change the ".jpg" to an extension like .avi it is not working any longer. For the code above VideoWriter.isOpened() returns true and for the same code with ".avi" it returns false. I tried a lot of combinations of file extensions and codecs (VideoWriter.fourcc), but it is never open.

Lets go ahead to my settings, I am using Intellij (2020.1.2) and openCV 440 is linked this way:
[image]

The only additional lib is the javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1

I was going with this [example](https://riptutorial.com/opencv/example/28548/creating-a-video-with-opencv--java-) in the first place, but it was never working that way for me.
I am very grateful for any suggestions

BR Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are creating `H264` codec `VideoWriter` but trying to get `.avi` codec video.

Here is the correct codec format for .avi or .mp4:

```
int fourcc = VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'J','P','G');
writer.open("images/out.avi", fourcc,
                videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS), frameSize, true);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041735/opencv-for-java-videowriter-cant-open) is similar problem and also [opencv documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#ac3478f6257454209fa99249cc03a5c59) for VideoWriter

Comment: Ohh damn, I tried so many things but I guess not MJPG with avi, thank you Yunus.
BUT it was still not working,  videoCapture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS) is returning 0 for some reason... [See github](https://github.com/openpnp/opencv/issues/32)
Just fixed it with an constant value, thank you again Yunus